# Plot convex-hull in 3D using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, convex-hull

I am trying to use `plotly` to plot the 3D convex-hull of a set of points. I am using `Mesh3d` objects but the surfaces are not created correctly (see the picture below). How can I fix this?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools, math, numpy as np

from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

# This simply creates a set of points:
n = 3
m = 3
E = np.array(list(itertools.product(np.arange(-1, 1.1, .5), repeat=m)))
V = [
 [-2.20676418,  1.53670924, -1.5541674 ],
 [ 0.63437404,  0.07306301,  3.82253086],
 [ 3.19989112,  0.71987311,  2.79373418]
]
x = np.array([np.dot(V, e) for e in E])

# Then I compute the convex hull using scipy:
xc = x[ConvexHull(x).vertices]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(x=xc[:, 0], y=xc[:, 1], z=xc[:, 2], color="blue", opacity=.5))
fig
```

Current output is:

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to add a pic of the expected output?

Comment: It's kind of difficult for me because I don't know how to generate them (hence the question =D). This one should be a kind of "stretched" 3-D cube, with all faces being parallelogram.

Comment: @rpanai If you replace `V` by `np.identity(3)`, it should be standard 3D cube, but it's currently a flat square with my version.

Comment: using your code I'm can' see the green point. Did you forget to add a scatterplot to your trace?

Comment: @rpanai Yes, sorry. I've updated the question with the code that matches the output (and I've reduced opacity to clearly see the issue).

Comment: I don't know if it might be related but you can have a look at this [example](https://plot.ly/~empet/14165.embed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you miss is the [alphahull](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#mesh3d-alphahull) option.

If you want a convex hull you need to add `alphahull=0`:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools, math, numpy as np

from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

# This simply creates a set of points:
n = 3
m = 3
E = np.array(list(itertools.product(np.arange(-1, 1.1, .5), repeat=m)))
V = [
 [-2.20676418,  1.53670924, -1.5541674 ],
 [ 0.63437404,  0.07306301,  3.82253086],
 [ 3.19989112,  0.71987311,  2.79373418]
]
x = np.array([np.dot(V, e) for e in E])

# Then I compute the convex hull using scipy:
xc = x[ConvexHull(x).vertices]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(x=xc[:, 0], 
                        y=xc[:, 1], 
                        z=xc[:, 2], 
                        color="blue", 
                        opacity=.5,
                        alphahull=0))
fig
```

will give you the vube you want:

[image: resutl]